# Understanding for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

Can someone help me to understand below code

I am resetting IFS to newline in 2nd line of the script itself. This value is read by out for command . Inside inner for command i am resetting IFS value to :

1) How IFS value is getting reset to New Line again after the first iteration of the outer loop as outer for loop is beginning from 3rd line and i am assigning newline character to IFS in 2nd line .

2) When i am doing echo $IFS in the outer loop and inner loop it is coming as blank. Any idea why.

Can someone explain how does this work

### test.txt:

```
cat test.txt

oracle:dba
network:admin
system:engineer
```

### test.sh:

```
cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash
# changing the IFS value

IFSOLD=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for entry in $(cat test.txt)
do
    echo "Values in $entry "
    IFS=:
    for value in $entry
    do
      echo " $value"
    done
done



sh test.sh

Values in oracle:dba
 oracle
 dba
Values in network:admin
 network
 admin
Values in system:engineer
 system
 engineer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFS` doesn't need to be reset for the outer loop. The result of `$(cat test.txt)` is split using `IFS` before the loop starts, it isn't split again each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `for` loop to [iterate over the lines of a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); use a `while` loop.

Then use `read` to split each line into an array of individual values.

```
while IFS= read -r entry; do
    echo "Values in $entry"
    IFS=: read -a values <<< "$entry"
    for value in "${values[@]}"; do
        echo " $value"
    done
done < test.txt
```